# How to explicitly invoke default method simply, without reflection and dynamic Proxy?

Tags: java, methods, java-8, default

I was reading about default methods in Java 8 and I got stuck in one thing - is there a way to invoke default method from interface without implementing it, or using dynamic Proxy? By using just a simple way, like in following methods:

```
interface DefaultTestInterface{
    default void method1(){
        //default method
    }
}
class ImplementingClass implements DefaultTestInterface{
    public void method1(){
        //default method invocation in implementing method
        DefaultTestInterface.super.method1();
    }
    void method2(){
        //default method invocation in implementing class
        DefaultTestInterface.super.method1();
    }
}
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //is there any way to simply invoke default method without using proxy and reflection?
    }
}
```

I read similar questions, but the [first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19976487/explicitly-calling-a-default-method-in-java) was connected only with invocation in implementing method, and two others was connected with [dynamic Proxy using reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19976487/explicitly-calling-a-default-method-in-java) and  [reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22614746/how-do-i-invoke-java-8-default-methods-refletively).

Those solutions are quite complicated and I am wondering if there is simpler way of doing it. I also read those articles, but I didn't found solution for my problem. I would be grateful for any help.

Comment: So you want to use a instance method without a instance???

Comment: There is some confusion in your question. A *default method* of a java 8 interface is already an implementation. If you don't have a class specific behavior that need a different implementation, you just implement the interface, omitting the method that you want to use as default. If you want to call a method from an *interface* than consider to use the *static* keyword to define it, instead.

Comment: No @fabian, I was thinking about solution with instantiation included somehow.

Comment: A default method is already implemented.  You don't have to re-implement it .

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If the interface has only one method, or all its methods have default implementations, all you need to do is creating an anonymous implementation that does *not* implement the method that you wish to call:

```
(new DefaultTestInterface() {}).method1();
```

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/KUdAy5)

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly the solution, which I was looking for.

Comment: @Michał Szewczyk: your question explicitly says “*without implementing it*” and this answer *is* implementing it. That simply doesn’t make any sense. It boils down to you having actually asked “how do I implement an interface?”…

Comment: @Holger Technically, you are absolutely right: this *is* an implementation of the interface. However, this degenerate implementation does not look like much of an implementation - in fact, I'm sure that many programmers, myself included, wouldn't spot the implementation on a cursory reading.

Comment: Indeed, but I’m refraining from calling that an advantage.