# Invoking a default method from an interface without the interface's name

Tags: java, invoke

Say I have an interface A, and a class B that implements A.
A defines a function foo() with some default implementation, and B overrides this default implementation and implements foo() as well.

I would like to call A.foo() default implementation using **invoke(obj, args) function**, since I don't know what interface foo() is defined in in run time.

I know that if I wanted to use invoke on B's implementation in run time (say I have aClass that holds B) I'd do something like:
`aClass.getMethod("foo", args).invoke(aClass.newInstance(), args);`

How do I do the above for A.foo?
**EDIT: I also only have the method's name, which I could only use to obtain its Method object, so I can't explicity call foo like A.super.foo().**

SAMPLE CODE:
`public interface A {
    default String foo() {return "foo";} 
}`

`public class B implements A {
}`

`Class<?> anInterface = Class.forName("A");`
`Class<?> aClass = Class.forName("B");`
`Method aMethod = A.getMethod("foo", null)`

How do I call A.foo() with only this variables?

Comment: A.super.foo() ?

Comment: @Steephen. A is unknown, all OP probably has is Class object.

Comment: @Steephen My bad, I also don't know A has foo! I actually have a method object of foo(), so I can't explicitly call foo! Updating the question right away!

Comment: It would help to post some sample code instead of trying to describe it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I invoke Java 8 default methods reflectively](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22614746/how-do-i-invoke-java-8-default-methods-reflectively)

Comment: since it is not a static method, you can't call A.foo(). but you can do this way: new A() {}.foo(); not sure is it your expect :)